# Python - Multiple main rply grammar grammar rules

Tags: python, parsing, ply

Here is an python-rply code I pulled from [here](https://pypi.org/project/rply/) as an example:

```py
from rply import ParserGenerator, LexerGenerator
from rply.token import BaseBox

lg = LexerGenerator()
# Add takes a rule name, and a regular expression that defines the rule.
lg.add("PLUS", r"\+")
lg.add("MINUS", r"-")
lg.add("NUMBER", r"\d+")

lg.ignore(r"\s+")

# This is a list of the token names. precedence is an optional list of
# tuples which specifies order of operation for avoiding ambiguity.
# precedence must be one of "left", "right", "nonassoc".
# cache_id is an optional string which specifies an ID to use for
# caching. It should *always* be safe to use caching,
# RPly will automatically detect when your grammar is
# changed and refresh the cache for you.
pg = ParserGenerator(["NUMBER", "PLUS", "MINUS"],
        precedence=[("left", ['PLUS', 'MINUS'])], cache_id="myparser")

@pg.production("main : expr")
def main(p):
    # p is a list, of each of the pieces on the right hand side of the
    # grammar rule
    return p[0]

@pg.production("expr : expr PLUS expr")
@pg.production("expr : expr MINUS expr")
def expr_op(p):
    lhs = p[0].getint()
    rhs = p[2].getint()
    if p[1].gettokentype() == "PLUS":
        return BoxInt(lhs + rhs)
    elif p[1].gettokentype() == "MINUS":
        return BoxInt(lhs - rhs)
    else:
        raise AssertionError("This is impossible, abort the time machine!")

@pg.production("expr : NUMBER")
def expr_num(p):
    return BoxInt(int(p[0].getstr()))

lexer = lg.build()
parser = pg.build()

class BoxInt(BaseBox):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def getint(self):
        return self.value
```

In this basic python-rply code, you can add and subtract numbers. Suppose I wanted to add a new element to this code, like a variable. From what I observe, I will have to add a new *main* grammar rule at the `@pg.production("main : expr")` part right before the `main` function is defined. My question is how will I add a new *main* grammar rule? Will I just add another decorator like this:

```py
@pg.production("main : expr")
@pg.production("main : <MY_NEW_ELEMENT_STUFF>")
```

If so, is there a more efficient way to do it (If I add a few more elements there, it will get very cramped)?

**NOTE: I am using [rply](https://pypi.org/project/rply/), not [ply](https://pypi.org/project/ply/), but they are very similar.**

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "cramped", but I don't think it's the same thing that I mean when I use that word ("forced into a space which is too small", "uncomfortably unable to move"). Anyway, it's a minor point but it would be useful what your goal actually is.

Comment: @rici By cramped I mean if I add many elements, there will be a lot of `@pg.production("main : <MY_NEW_ELEMENT_STUFF>")`, which I don't really want.

Comment: @rici I forgot to add; My goal is to add a variable to the example code, but I don't really need that in an answer... All I need in an answer is a way to add new main grammar rules.

Comment: Regardless, variables are usually in the category of expressions, not top-level syntaxes; I'd expect to see `expr: VARIABLE`. And, of course, other things like `expr: '(' expr ')'`. But then `main: expr` is a bit wierd, too. That would only handle a single expression. Usually input will consist of a stream of expressions (or even statements), possibly separated by newlines or semicolons.

Comment: @rici Is there a way I can change my code to make it accept multiple expressions?

Comment: If you really want to have more than one top-level syntax, you need to add more than one grammar rule. Why is that a problem for you?

Comment: I was just wondering *how to* add one more grammar rule...

Comment: Have you looked at any examples? I recommend the various calculator examples in the bison manual as a starting point.

Comment: @rici No, I haven't looked at very many examples, as rply ones aren't very easy to find.

Comment: Grammars are grammars.

Comment: Afaik, the only way to add additional rules in rply is to use multiple decorators. Is that really a problem?

Comment: @rici No, that isn't a very big problem at the start. My concern is, once many elements are added, it will be very hard to navigate the file with all the `@pg.production("main : <MY_NEW_ELEMENT_STUFF>")`

Comment: Here is the examples section in the Bison manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Examples. Even if you don't use C, the actions should be simple enough to follow and there is a giid description.

Comment: @rici Thank you... Could you quickly add an example of the multi-decorator grammar use? I just want to check that the example I gave above works (I haven't tested it).

Comment: I agree that it's a lot nicer to have the entire grammar in one piece, without intervening chunks of semantic actions. Neither ply nor rply are very good at that; there's a lot of syntactic noise and boilerplate. My advice is to keep your action functions short; put complicated semantics into other functions. Even so, it takes at least three lines for even a simple rule. I generally prefer bison, but it doesn't have a Python interface.

Comment: ... the multiple decorator is shown in the example you quote in your question!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191415/discussion-between-xilpex-and-rici).

Comment: But I don't like that style much. I prefer to have a separate action for every non-trivial production. As in my answer to your other question.